# android FileNotFoundException when getting files in internal storage

Tags: android, file, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to print a JSON file to string in android.

After clicking a button, then a JSON is printed.

These are the codes of that button:

```
public void startReadJSONButtonHandler(View view) throws Exception {    

    String yourFilePath = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/busStop.json";
    System.out.println(yourFilePath);
    File yourFile = new File(yourFilePath);

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(yourFile);    
    String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
    fin.close();
    
    System.out.println(ret);
}
```

The file do exists in "yourFilePath", I checked it in file explorer.

And when I run it, it returns this kind of error:

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdates/files/Download/busStop.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:160)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdates.MainActivity.startReadJSONButtonHandler(MainActivity.java:418)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It says the JSON file doesn't exists so returns a FileNotFoundException.

Do you have ideas of that?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You cannot check that path with a file explorer as getFilesDir is private to your app. No other app has access.

Comment: Use yourFile.exists() to check.

Comment: I got it, checked the file doesn't existing. The directory pointing is wrong.

Comment: The file I saw is in another location, made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks blackapps, I made to read the file.

The reason for me can't read the file is pointing to wrong direction.

Change this:

```
String yourFilePath = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/busStop.json";
```

To this:

```
File yourFilePath = MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```